# conda bug with keras package installs tensorflow even if tensorflow-gpu is already installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

I wanted share a problem I encountered and the solution I found that worked on my system.

For reference, this is my environment:
Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit,
nVidia GPU,
conda 4.5.2

I created a conda virtual environment and installed tensorflow-gpu (which resulted in 1.7.0 being installed which is not the latest, but is fine for my purposes).

I then did
`$ conda install keras`

keras was installed correctly, BUT it also installed tensorflow non-gpu version, which I cannot use.

This seems like a dependency bug in which keras package does not recognize tensorflow-gpu package as installed.

I was forced to remove tensorflow (non-gpu package) and to use

```
$ python3.6 -m pip install keras
```

This worked, but I would rather have consistent conda managed packages.

I hope that Anaconda fixes this, but in the meantime, you can try my solution.

BTW, don't even get me started on why I couldn't just use pip or pip3 instead of "python3.6 -m pip". Python 3.6 and 3.5 on Ubuntu at least are at war with each other causing all kinds of "module not found" problems. But that's for another post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [keras-gpu](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/keras-gpu)

```
conda install -c anaconda keras-gpu
```

Where `-c anaconda` indicates a channel where to look for the package. (You may want to try the default `conda install keras-gpu` or if you know about other channels, use them).

---

About python versions conflicting, it's a good idea to create specific environments, so you can also try different versions of tensorflow + keras without conflicts.

On my machine, using the intel version of python was a great deal for processing speed (although you're going to use GPU, not my case)

Create a new environment:

```
#anaconda version
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda

#intel version
conda create -n yourenvname intelpython3_core python=3
    #can also be specific, like python=3.5
```

Then you activate your environment:

```
source activate yourenvname
```

And install and use everything with this environment activated.

If using intel Python, it's interesting to follow the rest of the process here to use the optimized intel distributions of numpy, scipy and others: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-distribution-for-python-with-anaconda

More info on environments: https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/

Comment: With `conda install keras`, my tensorflow was downgraded to 1.5.0. It's ok for me, and something similar might happen to you.

Comment: Thank you: I did switch to keras-gpu. But I discovered another problem with conda. Once you install cpu version of  keras, it installs cpu version of tensorflow. At that point, it is impossible to uninstall cpu version of tensorflow. I even tried conda clean -a after I did the remove command. Nothing worked. I had to delete my virtual environment and the entire anaconda directory. Then I had to uninstall conda and reinstall it. At that point, installing the gpu versions worked.